# Each item from List of BigDecimals compared to int

Tags: java

I have a list of BigDecimals that have different format (`1,900.4500` or `69.4444`) for which I have to compare to some other value.

```
public boolean abc(int value) {
..
List<BigDecimals> list = getListOfBD(); //it returns values from the table exact as they are
return list.stream().allMatch(val -> val.intValue() == value)
  // or
return list.stream().allMatch(val -> val.intValue() == value)
}
```

Problem is that I need to compare the `value` (which will be always same format, regardless whether it'd be `int` or other - it had to always one type) to different types from the list. How to do that? `intValue()` won't do the job because it simplifies the number and the results are not reliable.
I need to compare that the `value` is `==` or `>` that the `val` so I need each decimal point to be included. Number can be parsed, I don't mind.

Comment: most likely, you're looking for generics

Comment: What do you mean by "different formats"? A `BigDecimal` doesn't **have** a format at all? All it cares about is which digits it holds (and how many trailing zeroes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First convert value into BigDecimal and then use compareTo

```
 BigDecimal a = BigDecimal.valueOf( value )
 a.compareTo(val)
```